# can't assign to function call to eulers method program

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I keep on getting an error that states, " can't assign to function call" to my function p, I'm confused on how I should get rid of this error?

I tried to define p but it still does't work.

```
   tmax=10            
   N=100             
   dt=tmax/N       
   t=linspace(0,tmax,N+1)     
   h=.2            
   r=.1           
   p(0) =3         

   p=zeros(1,N+1)    

   for n in range(1,N):           

      p(n+1)=(1+r*dt)*p(n)-h*dt;              

   plot(t,p)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `p(0) = 3`?

Comment: Given that `p` is `np.zeros` I think they're trying to set the value of index 0 to `3`. In that case, the syntax is to use square brackets, not parenthesis `p[0] = 3`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think you use numpy. And You want to print out data as graph.

I tested it as matplotlib in jupyter notebook. So, Please change it what you want to use.

Please refer code fixed as below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

%matplotlib inline
tmax=10            
N=100             
dt=tmax/N       
t=np.linspace(0,tmax,N+1)     
h=.2            
r=.1           
p=np.zeros((1,N+1))[0]
for n in range(1,N):           
    p[n+1]=(1+r*dt)*p[n]-h*dt;              
plt.plot(t,p)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from `p(0) = 3`. You are trying to call a function with an argument 0 by writing `p(0)`. This may return something or maybe not, but you definitely cannot assign it to a value of 3. Maybe this is close to what you're looking for:

```
# Python Code to find approximation 
# of a ordinary differential equation 
# using euler method. 

# Consider a differential equation 
# dy / dx =(x + y + xy) 
def func( x, y ): 
    return (x + y + x * y) 

# Function for euler formula 
def euler( x0, y, h, x ): 
    temp = -0

    # Iterating till the point at which we 
    # need approximation 
    while x0 < x: 
        temp = y 
        y = y + h * func(x0, y) 
        x0 = x0 + h 

    # Printing approximation 
    print("Approximate solution at x = ", x, " is ", "%.6f"% y) 

# Driver Code 
# Initial Values 
x0 = 0
y0 = 1
h = 0.025

# Value of x at which we need approximation 
x = 0.1

euler(x0, y0, h, x)
```